# Instantiating a Bazel macro twice with same generated output file

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, starlark, skylark, bazel-extra-action

Suppose I have a Bazel macro that is using a generator rule to generate an output file given an input file:

```
def my_generator(
        name,
        input_file,
        output_file,
        **kwargs):
    args = []
    args.extend(["--arg1", "$(location %s)" % output_file])
    args.extend(["arg2", "$(locations %s)" % input_file])

    cmd_params = " ".join(args)

    native.genrule(
        name = name,
        srcs = [input_file],
        outs = [output_file],
        cmd = "python $(location //path/to:target_generator) %s" % cmd_params,
        tools = ["/path/to/tool:mytool"],
    )
```

Then I was previously using this macro as:

```
my_generator(
    name = "gen1",
    input_file = ":targetToGeneratetextFile",
    output_file = "outputfile.txt",
    visibility = ["//myproject/oath/to/current/package/test:__subpackages__"],
)
```

where a target is passed as `input_file`. This was working.

Then I wanted to reuse it with a different input but to generate the same output, where the input is now a file within the project but in another folder.

```
my_generator(
    name = "gen2",
    input_file = "//path/to/the/file/realFile.txt",
    output_file = "outputfile.txt",
    visibility = ["//myproject/oath/to/current/package/test:__subpackages__"],
)
```

I am getting two errors in this way:

1. For how it is, Bazel cannot find the `realFile.txt`: it tries to read it as a target:

> no such package '//path/to/the/file/realFile.txt': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package

If I copy the file in the current package folder, it is able to read it.

2. Bazel is complaining that `gen1` and `gen2` are writing/overwriting the same output file `outputfile.txt`:

> Error in genrule: generated file 'outputfile.txt' in rule 'gen2' conflicts with existing generated file from rule 'gen1', defined at ...

How can I solve these issues?

I think  that the problem is that these two calls are both executed, whereas I would like them to be executed depending on some target, i.e., target A needs only run `gen1` and target B `gen2` exclusively. I do not if that is possible but for example moving each of these call inside the target they belong to might be a solution that avoids this issue.

**EDIT**
I was thinking as solution to do something like:

```
my_generator(
    name = "gen2",
    input_file = select({
       ":opt1": [":targetToGeneratetextFile"],
       ":opt2": ["realTextFile.txt"],
       "//conditions:default": [":targetToGeneratetextFile"],
    }),
    output_file = "outputfile.txt",
    visibility = ["//myproject/oath/to/current/package/test:__subpackages__"],
)
```

with proper `config_setting` and then call it from the target with the proper flag but I am getting the error:

> expected value of type 'string' for element 0 of attribute 'srcs' in 'genrule' rule, but got select({":opt1": [":targetToGeneratetextFile"], ":opt2": ["realTextFile.txt"],"//conditions:default": [":targetToGeneratetextFile"],
> })

Comment: Is there a BUILD file in the same directory as `//path/to/the/file/realFile.txt`? e.g. `//path/to/the/file:BUILD`?

Comment: Also that target appears to malformed `//path/to/the/file/realFile.txt` should be `//path/to/the/file:realFile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

The [label](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-ref.html#labels) `//path/to/the/file/realFile.txt` is shorthand for `//path/to/the/file/realFile.txt:realFile.txt`, aka `<repository root>/path/to/the/file/realFile.txt/realFile.txt`. Depending on where the deepest-nested folder with a BUILD file is (which determines the package), you're looking for something like `//path/to/the/file:realFile.txt` or `//path/to:the/file/realFile.txt` instead.

You can't have two rules which write the same file, because then Bazel can't tell which way to build it if you `bazel build` the file. Some alternatives:

- Put them in separate packages (aka separate folders with BUILD files)
- Name them differently, like `gen1_outputfile.txt` and `gen2_outputfile.txt`, or `gen1/outputfile.txt` and `gen2/outputfile.txt`. You could automate this in the macro like `srcs = [name + '/outputfile.txt']`.
- Use a single rule to generate it with an appropriate select, like your edit.

With the `select`, you're trying to create something like this:

```py
genrule(
    srcs = select({..., "//conditions:default": [":targetToGeneratetextFile"]}),
    ...
)
```

but as written you have this instead:

```py
genrule(
    srcs = [select({..., "//conditions:default": [":targetToGeneratetextFile"]})],
    ...
)
```

Effectively, between the list in the `select`'s value and the macro body, you're creating a nested list. I would change your macro argument to `input_files` and then do `srcs = input_files` in the body, so the caller of the macro can bundle things into lists as desired.

Comment: In your answer you have put a `select` in the `genrule`: if you put it here, do you have to put a `select` also when calling the macro that uses the genrule (as I did in my edit: `my_generator` there is using a `select`: is this correct?)? (i.e., instead of having `gen1` and `gen2`, having only one of them with a `select`? If not how shall I call the macro? Just once or create two instances?